# How to use multiple concepts per text gen component in Jetbrains MPS 2017.1?

Tags: code-generation, dsl, mps

I created a simple DSL in JetBrains MPS for an automation task at hand. The DSL allows defining information objects which in turn shall be used for code generation. I am able to generate my models - but I am struggling to find a way to assign an additional text gen component to the same language concept, i.e. what I am trying to achieve is:

- information object to db model (python)
- information object to db access layer methods (python)
- information object to protobuf message
- ...

I feel that I got a wrong understanding on how to use this. Any ideas on how to achieve different outputs for the same language concept?

Comment: Each of this information objects should have it own file or do you want to create all of them in a single file?

Comment: Ideally there will be different output files for each layer, i.e. one output file with all the model definitions, one output file containing the protobuf schema definitions, etc. I found a somewhat workaround solution [here](https://mps-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206613545-TextGen-multiple-files-output-per-concept-instance-#community_comment_203694104) - thing is, this still will not allow me to specify various text gen components for my non-root concepts.

Comment: another idea came to my mind: Removing all the text gen components from my actual language and define one language that extends my base language for each layer/file to be generated. These additional languages will only comprise the text gen transformations but no actual language concepts. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPS will only allow you to have single textgen definition per concept.

The MPS way to do what you want to do is to do this before textgen with a model to model transformation.

Define additional concept for your three objects you want to create. Their content is basically the same as in the root concept that you already have. Theses concept will only be used to define your textgen. So next define the textgen for theses concepts.

Now you still need to create instances of these because of course you don't want the user to specify theses information multiple times. To do this you need to define a generator. Generators are used for model to model transformations in MPS.

By default your language should already have a generator. In the generator is a mapping configuration `main`. In there you create a root mapping for each of the of the three new concepts you created. Each of this rules has as the input concept the one that the user specifies and as a template one of the new concepts. You can create a new template by pressing `alt + enter` in the editor and choose the concept you want to create. Make sure you set `keep input root` to `true` instead of `default`.

Inside the template you specify a `COPY_SRC` to copy all of the contents from the input to the output.

What then happens during generation is that MPS will create three new concepts out of the one that the user created in the original model and after the executes the textgen for all of them. This also allows you to create different files for each root.

I think the [DEMO 1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/MPSD20171/Generator+User+Guide+Demo1) project shows some of the things you will need for this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am still struggling at one point - I am not sure what I should select when hitting `alt + enter` for setting the root template of a mapping rule (see [screenshot](http://imgur.com/n2GPbOV)

Comment: Don't mind my question. Forgot to add the language to "Used languages". Works like a charm now!

Comment: @JanWendland Could you please elaborate more on what you did? I can follow all steps described here but when previewing generated text I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider the plaintextgen plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8444-com-dslfoundry-plaintextgen